# restarter service in solaris 11.4

Tags: unix, solaris

i have changed a proprty for myservice in Solaris 11.4 . but when i refresh the service and run svcprop by this commands, property have not changed. why this change is not permanently?

```
root@Host:~# svcprop svc:/application/myservice
.
.
.
restarter/auxiliary_state astring none
root@Host:~# svccfg -s svc:/application/myservice setprop restarter/auxiliary_state=ct_ev_ex
root@Host:~# svcadm refresh svc:/application/myservice
root@Host:~# svcprop svc:/application/myservice
.
.
.
restarter/auxiliary_state astring none
```

Answer (score 1):

That property is managed by svc.startd, it's read-only as far as users are concerned.